# Electron Custom Protocol with oAuth redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, electron, nuxt.js

I'm using discord oAuth2 is a vue/nuxt/electron application and i need to create a custom protocol to handle the oAuth2 code. I would like to have something like this in the end: `myapp://auth/callback?code=codehere`

I have tried various answers related to this but none of them have been logical for my use.

For example:

```
app.whenReady().then(() => {
protocol.registerSchemesAsPrivileged([{
    scheme: 'myapp',
    privileges: {
      standard: true,
      secure: true
    }
  },
])
})
```

I know electron-builder has a protocol option but i'm not sure that that suits my needs either.

Answer (score 3):

Electron has an option that you can call like this to register a private URI scheme:

```js
app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient('myapp');
```

If it helps I have a working desktop code sample using Electron that you can run from here. Hopefully, it helps you to progress things:

- [Code Sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.desktopsample.final)
- [Write Up](https://authguidance.com/2018/01/26/final-desktop-sample-overview/)